# Custom UITableViewCell designed in xib has nil's

Tags: swift, uitableview

I used to design custom cells right in a main storyboard and everything worked great till I tried to design it in external "xib" file.
I found it really more easier to design, setting constraints etc.
 
Obviously, there was a UITableViewCell class for both ways.
I did all new IBOutlets for new xib's, Xcode shows no errors, everything looks fine and has to work great. 
But, party is over with

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on the `self.photo.image = photo`

```
class CellForMessages: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var surname: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var count: UILabel!

override func prepareForReuse() {

    self.photo = nil
    self.name.text = nil
    self.surname.text = nil
    self.count.text = nil
}

func fillWithContent(photo: UIImage, name: String, surname: String, count: Int) {
    self.photo.image = photo
    self.name.text = name
    self.surname.text = surname
    self.count.text = String(count)
}
```

Controller file has all stuff like:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "messagesProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CellForMessages
cell.fillWithContent(photo: image!, name: self.profiles[indexPath.item].userName!, surname: profiles[indexPath.item].userSurname!, count: count)
```

I have even tried to add this piece of code, but some people told me that it is not necessary and can erase smth,
However I tried and error still exists.

```
tableView.register(CellForMessages.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "messagesProfileCell")
```

All outlets are up to date and in main Storyboard identifier is set.

What am I missing?
I do not want to return to old way of cell design.

Thanks!!!

Comment: this line self.photo = UIImageView() seems wrong

Comment: as per @zombie told    self.photo = UIImageView() for outlet having already a memory . if you want better to do  set imageView ka  Image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `UIImageView` loaded by your File Owner in your XIB by `self.photo = UIImageView()`. You should set the imageView's image to nil instead.

```
@IBOutlet weak var photo: UIImageView?
@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var surname: UILabel?
@IBOutlet weak var count: UILabel?

override func prepareForReuse() {

    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.photo?.image = nil
    self.name?.text = nil
    self.surname?.text = nil
    self.count?.text = nil
}
```

You can add `?` to the end of your outlets to make them optional, so if one of them (for whatever reason) are nil, it won't crash. This means when using any of your outlets, you must use `?` after the name e.g. `self.photo?.image = nil`

Comment: Unfortunately, it has no effect

Comment: I did hard debug with print(profiles) and there is no missing data. So you mean it can crash on the first load when they obviously have no data?

Comment: okay, with optionals there is no crash. But table now is empty. It seems to be another question :) I checked again, in controller "fillWithContent" receives all necessary info